# I'm doing something wrong with SpotLights and shadows in Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, shadow, three.js

I have a really simple scene which has one .dae mesh in it, and a 7000*7000 plane underneath the mesh. I'd like it to be lit by a high `SpotLight`, so the mesh throws a shadow on the ground. But, something seems to be broken! No matter how high I put the `SpotLight`, it never lights up the plane! Also, it lights the mesh up only a little, while it is in a small square (perimeter).

You can see the situation here:
[image: Screenshot1, almost everything is dark]

As soon as I move the mesh (a monster) around, it wont be lit anymore.

This is how I instantiate the light:

```
// create a spotlight
self.spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight();

// set its position
self.spotLight.position.y = 1000; //I recon it needs to be relatively high so it lights up everything
self.spotLight.position.x = 0; //(0, 0) are the coordinates where the mesh is spawned, and are the center of the plane
self.spotLight.position.z = 0;
self.spotLight.castShadow = true;
```

This is how the plane is made:

```
//The plane.
self.plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(self.groundSize, self.groundSize), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x5C8A00}));
self.plane.receiveShadow = true;
self.plane.position.x = 0;
self.plane.position.y = -26;
self.plane.position.z = 0;
```

Also, here's another picture, this time, I've added a lot of `PointLights`:

[image: Screenshot2, everything is lit up.]

You can see how the shadow still disappears!

Now, what am I doing wrong here? AFAIK, light should disperse equally in all directions! And also, there is another problem, I seem to be unable to add multiple SpotLights on the scene! Everything slows down completely if I do so - is this intended? Maybe it's because I enabled shadows on all of them...

@Neil, the same thing happens in your code as well!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCXNQ/123/) showing a plane with Lambert material and a rotating cube that is casting a shadow, maybe you can see what is different to yours.

**edit**

Try playing about with some of the params, I can stop the clipping on my demo with:

```
spotLight.shadowCameraFov = 70;
```

update [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SCXNQ/123/) and moving [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SCXNQ/124/)

Comment: please see the edit I made, the same thing happens with your code as well.

Comment: @Bane - sorry i don't quite understand, do u mean the shadow is incorrect or that its clipped or something? Or do you mean if an object is moved you don't get the shadow?

Comment: The shadow seems cut off once the object moves further away. Like there is a rectangle in which the shadows can be drawn, and any shadows outside of it don't get drawn at all.

Comment: @Bane - might I suggest try a DirectionalLight for this type of behaviour as its designed for the whole scene

Comment: Yep, I figured out how to manipulate it now, thanks! I still don't get why doesn't it disperse equally...

Comment: use `renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;` to see the debug stuff